# Make highcharts bar-chart threshold line visible & labels not to overlap on one another

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart, label, threshold

I have a tornado chart created using bar-charts form Highcharts. I have set a threshold value and on either side of which there are low and high bars.

Now I need to make the threshold line visible. I also have a problem of labels getting overlapped when high, low and base values are equal.

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/xe7qL156/

Please help me to solve it. Thanks.

```
series: [{
        threshold: 29.5,
        name: 'Low',
        grouping: false,
        type: 'bar',
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 12.15,
        }, {
            x: 1,
            y: 15.45,
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 31.25,
        }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 12.15,
        }],
        labels: [10, 5, 1, 2]
    }, {
        threshold: 29.5,
        name: 'High',
        grouping: false,
        type: 'bar',
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 46.86,
        }, {
            x: 1,
            y: 42.28,
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 27.77,
        }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 46.86,
        }],
        labels: [30, 10, 3, 4]
    }]
```

Update: here is a mockup image of what I need
[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but I think you want a vertical line overthe bars at the 29.5 position ?

If so, you can do that with another series:

```
    series: [
    {type:'line',color:'black',zIndex:505,data:[[0,29.5],[4,29.5]]},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fsbqnw7m/

Alternatively, you can use the renderer API to draw a line wherever you want.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Comment: I have added a mockup image of what I need. Please take a look at that.

Comment: Then just edit second x-value for that line, see: http://jsfiddle.net/fsbqnw7m/1/

Comment: @PawełFus: I need something like in the mockup image. I don't want it to stop in between the bar. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Line can be added also as [plotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines) in particular place.